# Stop all logged in users from being able to edit all content

Tags: plone

I have noticed that a user who is logged in (who is not part of any group) can edit any item in my site. I would like to take advantage of the sharing functionality, and specify who can edit the content, but it seems to have no effect, since all logged in users can edit everything (and seem to be able to change permissions themselves). How can I make the site pay attention to the sharing settings?

I cant seem to find any documentation which describes this default behaviour making me wonder if it is just my setup.

Comment: This is not default behaviour. On `yoursi.te/manage`, in the security tab, what are the checkboxes for (to name a random candidate) "ATContentTypes: AddDocument" and "Modify portal content"?

Comment: Additionally, on `yoursi.te/portal_workflow/manage_selectWorkflows`, what's the workflow for Page? (If it's (Default), check the bottom of the page for the true value.) If you go to the contents tab, there to the workflow just found, there to states, public, permissions, what does it tell you? Does "Authenticated user" have "Modify portal content" or something like that?

Comment: Probably you played with the "Authenticated users" virtual group? It is the most dangerous Plone feature! Check if you gave it permissions in the groups control panel or directly on the site root.

Comment: Security for "ATContentTypes: AddDocument" and "Modify portal content" don't have the member or authenticated user boxes ticked.

Comment: I follow up to portal_workflow/simple_publication_workflow/states, but there is no "public" option, just "pending","private" and "publish".